# How to migrate a data type String to boolean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a class that has a parameter defined as a String, now I realized the type should be boolean, I would like to migrate the type from String to boolean.

I'm using Intellij and I have the option of migrating from a native type to another native type (e.g char --> int) but it does not work with String

[Type Migration in Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/type-migration.html) does not have relevant info in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: This feature is working fine for me. Are you using the latest version of the IDE? What error are you running into?

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate any type you like to any other type. It doesn't mean your code will be guaranteed work after any type migration though.

Consider this example.

```
private Class aClass = Class.class;
```

Here we have a Class object called aClass that stores a reference to the class Class. How confusing!

Since all classes in Java extend object. We can do a type migration from Class to Object, and we won't run into any errors with our code later.

```
private Object aClass = Class.class;
```

The above is still valid Java.

Now, if we want to convert say a String or char into a boolean, we'll get a popup saying it can't convert. We can click ignore so that it migrates the type, but now it will be invalid Java as you're trying to assign a char or String to a boolean type.

Here is a screenshot outlining this error:

[image: migration error image]

**IntelliJ doesn't modify the assignment to the variable, just its type. Correcting any compile errors as a result of migration is up to you.**